# Show diff of my pending wiki edits

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, revision-history

I have edited a Wiki entry, waiting for approval. For the time being, there is no way to see the diff I have done.

Suggestion: Permit somehow to view the diff of one's own pending wiki edits.

Expected result: Better quality of edits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8375494, reachable via your profile => Activity => All actions => Suggestions